# regex: put $ in [ ] in zero-width positive lookahead assertion

Tags: regex, perl

The following script is used to trim `t` at the end of the line

```
echo "test"|perl -pe "s/t(?=$)//g"
tes  #sucess

echo "test"|perl -pe "s/t(?=[\\$])//g"
test #fail
```

Why does the second one fail? Shouldn't the result also be "tes"?

Comment: You don't need the zerowidth lookahead assertion nor the `g` flag. `s/t$//` is sufficient.

Comment: Your second one-liner with the substitution `s/t(?=[\\$])//g` cannot run, it ends with the fatal error `Unmatched [ in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/t(?=[ <-- HERE \\5.016002)/` (because `$]` is a built-in variable that gets interpolated)

Answer (score 2):

it doesn't work because in the first script `$` is a *end of line* anchor, but in the second script, since it is  enclosed in a character class, the `$` is seen as a literal character.

Note that in the first script the use of a lookahead is useless since `$` is a zero-width assertion itself, so `t$` will match exactly the same substring.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case `$` is the end of the string. In second case it is the `$` sign it self.

Comment: Why `$` in the following case is the end of the line: `echo "tests"|perl -pe "s/s[t\\$]//g"`, but in the case of the question, it is just the `$` sign?

Comment: @MarkZar `\\\` escapes the special character funtionality.

Comment: I didn't get it. I used \\ and [ ] in both cases.

Comment: @MarkZar in this case `echo "test"|perl -pe "s/t(?=$)//g"` it is the end of the line because `$` is not escaped. In this case: `echo "test"|perl -pe "s/t(?=[\\$])//g"` it is the `$` because it is escaped.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I see. So I guess in perl `$` can never be used within `[ ]` to signify the end of a line, right? Because `"[$]"` or `"[\$]"` doesn't work, and `"[\\$]"` only signifies the `$` sign itself.